# a:focus not working well in a Reactjs Component

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have all my `<a>` tags with `:focus`, `:hover` and `:active` styled like this:

```
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
 background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.35) !important;
}
```

But the problem is, they don't work. I have to click like 2 times to see the `background color`
For example, on this menu

```
<div className="appBottomMenu">
      <Link to="/" className="item">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-home"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <Link className="item" to="/area">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-marker"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/community" className="item">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-browser"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/shop" className="item">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-shopping-cart"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/profile" className="item">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-user"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
```

How can I make `:focus`, `:hover` and `:active` wor on te first click?

Comment: To make it work you have to change `display` of `a` to `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Bellow code is working for me:

```js
const {Link} = ReactRouterDOM


const Example = () => {
  return(
  <ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
    <Link to = "/example">Example</Link> 
  </ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Example/>);
```

```css
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  background: rgba(199, 18, 18, 0.35) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```